# How can I create a performant, immutable array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have an array that's used a lot, such as an identity matrix, which I want to make sure isn't modified accidentally. How can I create a JavaScript array that can't be modified?

`Object.freeze` is probably what I want, but [jsperf reports that it's much slower than a regular array](http://jsperf.com/freeze-array-performance).

**EDIT:** Title to specify performance is a requirement. We've got a lot of WebGL calls to make!

**EDIT 2:** More specifically, this is for a browser-based WebGL game (hence the performance requirement), so whatever features are in the current JavaScript interpreters of Chrome and Firefox are available. Regarding social pressure with code reviews, absolutely! But we're still humans who make mistakes and occasionally write to the wrong variable.

Comment: i'm afraid that doesn't exist. it should be easy enough to create everytime.

Comment: @DanielA.White Easy, but not performant. Updating the title.

Comment: @Daniel A. White: if millions/second performance isn't enough for OP then presumably they won't accept creating some new object.

Comment: @a paid nerd: define "not performant" please

Comment: So 25 - 30,000,000 operations a second is not fast enough

Comment: its 5-6 times slower since its no longer an array.

Comment: @OJay Correct. Allocations and the subsequent garbage collection are now a major performance cost for us.

Comment: can't you use social means (code reviews) to audit against modifying the array?

Comment: @a paid nerd: so why not just use an array then? You don't trust yourself?

Comment: What support do you need (I doubt there is anything *faster* than an array with current JS engines, but in the interests of science I'm game to try - but I don't want to suggest a Proxy if it needs to work in IE 9).

Comment: Is there anyway to hide the array as a private variable inside a function, this will make it mutable only inside its parent function, and then create interface exposures on the parent function for interaction perhaps?

Comment: For those keeping score, Firefox handles the facade really well (almost array speeds) but has abysmal frozen performance, while Chrome handles frozen decently (but still too slow) while the facade is sometimes ridiculously slow (see the [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/freeze-array-performance/3) for more).

Comment: You have to create the `Array` instance for the identity matrix *once* and you have to freeze it *once*. Sounds like you are looking for a solution requiring a problem.

Comment: @OJay, Your thought was exactly my first thought too. You could expand further by "attaching" chosen Array.prototype functions to the facade's prototype.

Answer (score 4):

You could manually set the array's mutator methods:

```
var mutatorMethods = ['fill', 'pop', 'push', 'reverse', 'shift', 'sort', 'splice', 'unshift'];

function preventMutation() {
  throw new TypeError('Array is immutable');
}

function makeImmutableArray(origArray) {
  mutatorMethods.forEach(function(method) {
    origArray[method] = preventMutation;
  });

  return origArray;
}

var foo = makeImmutableArray(['foo', 'bar', 'baz']);
```

See this jsbin as an example: http://jsbin.com/zeser/1/edit

This however, only glazes over a bigger problem (considering one could still modify the array through direct indexing `foo[0] = 'froboz';`): Why do you need an immutable array?

Let me rephrase, who are you trying to prevent from modifying the array? If this is publically facing I would say make your own object and expose the kinds of methods you expect them to use. Adding one level of function calls to iterate is negligible to performance and it prevents exposing the mutator functions.

Lastly if you are protecting mutation from yourself then your coding by extreme paranoia. It adds complexity. Defensive Coding is better served (IMHO) for interactions from outside your system. Defending against your own mistakes only makes the code more complicated because you would be second guessing yourself and often lacking consistency in the plethora of if/else checks.

Instead I'd offer encapsulating the concept of an iterative object by making your own Array like object and using that.

Comment: not going to stop direct index assignment i.e. foo[0] = "notfoo"

Comment: I think at that point you should choose how you want to manage your interface to the immutable object. If you want to avoid index assignment I would suggest not using an array but your own object which could hide an array in a closure.

Comment: Not only is it clever, but in most browsers it is [performant too](http://jsperf.com/freeze-array-performance/3)!  (Firefox might get better milage out of `"use asm"` code, but I'm not capable of hand-writing ASM, so I can't test it).